# Interacting with leaflet popup containing React components

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, leaflet, popup

I am trying to interact with a popup in Leaflet. However, when I try to click the `CustomButton` inside of the popup, nothing happens, it wont even console log.

```
const popupContent = (
   <div>
       ...
       <CustomButton
          onClick={() => {
             ...
          }}
       />
   </div>
);

layer.bindPopup(() => ReactDOMServer.renderToString(popupContent));
```

Note: Using renderToString for minimal reproducibility. I am aware of [this](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/server/renderToString#removing-rendertostring-from-the-client-code)

I have worked around this by implementing a "React-less" solution, but am looking for something more elegant and scalable:

```
const popupContent = document.createElement("div");
popupContent.innerHTML = `
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
  ...
  <button data-id="${inventoryData.id}" class="select-button" style="background-color: #f5f5f5; color: #333; padding: 0.5rem 1rem; border: none; margin-top: 1rem; border-radius: 0.5rem; font-weight: bold; transition: background-color 0.3s;">Select</button>
</div>
`;

popupContent.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  const target = event.target as HTMLElement;
  if (target.classList.contains("select-button")) {
    const selectedId = target.getAttribute("data-id");
    console.log("Selecting inventory with ID:", selectedId);
    //* onClick Functionality Here */
  }
});

layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
```